# Cannot install guest additions (unknown filesystem type 'iso9660')

Tags: linux, virtualbox, guest-additions

I want to install the guest additions on my Linux Ubuntu VM (host is windows 10).
When I go to devices -> Insert guest additions in the VM I get the following error:

[image: error]

The guest additions .iso is in my Oracle/VirtualBox folder. What could the problem be? Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/596998/693277

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the posts in this thread fixed the problem, I tried "sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)", "sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso" as well as manually mounting it

Comment: How about rebooting the guest?

Comment: with`sudo reboot` ? That also didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311161/how-to-install-guest-additions-in-lubuntu-13-04

> Ubuntu
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get install dkms
> ```
>
> Reboot your guest system in order to activate the updates and then
>   proceed as described above:
>
> - Insert the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso CD file into your Linux guest's
>     virtual CD-ROM drive
>     [Don't do this, if the Storage tab shows it to be already attached to the virtual machine]
> - [open a terminal, ] Change to
>     the directory where your CD-ROM drive is mounted, and execute:
> - `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`